# angular: assigning ng-options dynamically, strange behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I am building an inline editable form.

My directive hands down ng-options to the template. The jade file:

```
div(input-inline-select="myobj.val" options="c.name for c in codes" tabindex="1")
```

In the directive:

```
scope.options = attr.options;
```

In the template rendering the select:

```
div(class="input_inline_edit_div")
  {{options}} 
  select(class="inline_edit_select" ng-options="{{options}}" ng-model="model" on-enter="save()" on-esc="cancel()" ng-show="editMode" tabindex="{{tabindex}}" ng-focus="edit()")
  span(ng-mouseenter="showEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="showEdit = false")
    span(ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="edit()" )
      div(class="inline_edit_text")
        {{model}}
```

What happens is that the first `{{options}}` prints correctly `c.name for c in codes`, but the one at `ng-options="{{options}}"` doesn't, and the code in fact breaks and there are no options visible. Any idea why that is? Why does options correctly expand on its "own" but not as an attribute value?

Comment: I begin to have the feeling that it might be some timing issue...maybe. Maybe not all objects are initialized at the moment I try to access them...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `{{}}`

```
ng-options="options"
```

Comment: doesn't help. I still have an error in the console: (was there with the brackets as well)  `http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ngOptions/iexp?p0=options&p1=%3Cselect%20ng-options%3D"<select ng-options="options"...`